# Is it possible to group files by some complex logic and then operate them with bash/fish?

Tags: bash, fish

I download some videos and some of them are split into several parts:

```
001 aaaa part1.mp4
001 aaaa part2.mp4
002 bbbb part1.mp4
003 cccc part1.mp4
003 cccc part2.mp4
004 dddd part1.mp4
004 dddd part2.mp4
005 eeee part1.mp4
006 ffff part1.mp4
007 gggg part1.mp4
008 hhhh part1.mp4
```

In the above files, the `001 ...` `003 ...` and `004 ...` are split files, and others are not, even if they have `part1.mp4` in name.

I want to find and combine the split files with some tools, like `mp4box`.

In order to do this, I need to do:

1. Group the files by the numbers of each file in the beginning, and the groups which contain more than one file, it's the part files I need. So the `001/003/004` file will be found.
2. Generate new file name for them by removing the `part?.mp4`. For `001 aaaa part1.mp4` and `001 aaaa part2.mp4`, it will generate `001 aaaa.mp4`
3. Call `mp4box -add "001 aaaa part1.mp4" -cat "001 aaaa part2.mp4" "001 aaaa.mp4"` to combine them
4. Repeat this for all the part files

I tried to do this with fish/bash, but failed. In the end, I use some other programming languages to complete, but I still want to know is it possible to do it with fish or bash.

Comment: Do you want to rename the files that aren't split also? Or should they keep `part#` in their names?

Comment: @EtanReisner I guess we will never know.

Comment: @EtanReisner Both OK, thanks for the question to make it clear

Comment: @Freewind Have you tried my solution with no success ?

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein Sorry I forgot to choose the best answer. Thanks for your excellent answer, I hope I can give your more votes, but I just chose faho's answer, since the fish solution looks a little bit simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fish, I'd iterate not over the files but over the numbers, so something like

```
for num in (printf '%03d\n' (seq 1 8)) # Pad the numbers to the given length - assuming they are all three digits long
    set -l files $num* # This will generate a list with as many elements as there are matching files, so if there's no file, there's zero elements
    count $files >/dev/null; or continue # Skip numbers that aren't used
    set -l name (string replace -r 'part.' '' -- $files[1]) # Or sed if you are using fish < 2.3
    if test (count $files) -gt 1
        mp4box -add $files[1] -cat $files[2..-1] $name # Assuming all but the last argument after cat are taken to be files to concatenate, otherwise it's a little more complicated
    else
        mv $files $name # If there's one file, just rename it
    end
end
```

Comment: Which version of fish are you using? I'm using `2.2.0`, and it reports `fish: Unknown command 'string'`

Comment: I'm using git master (which will turn into 2.3.0 soon). That's why the comment said "if you are not using git fish".

Comment: Cool, I use the latest fish from git, and it's working well. The string feature is really a killer

Answer (score 2):

The following script might be helpful to you. I wrote the general pattern which you'll need to modify in order for it to work with `mp4box`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Iterate over all file name prefixes which represent a split file.
for i in 001 003 004; do

    # An array to hold paths of split files.
    arr=()

    # Find all files in present-working-directory ( PWD ) which have the current prefix in their file name,
    # and add them to the split files array sorted by 'part' number.
    while read -rd '' f; do
        # The index of the entry. Parts must be sorted.
        num=${f##* part}
        num=${num%.*}
        # Put "$f" in the correct array cell, according to its part index.
        arr[10#$num]=$f
    done < <(find . -type f -name "$i *.mp4" -print0)

    # We're making arr not sprase, so we'll know for sure that arr[0] is not empty,
    # from which we'll derive the destination file name.
    arr=("${arr[@]}")

    # If we have more than a single split file in the split files array, then
    if (( ${#arr[@]} > 1 )); then
        # Create a new name for the destination mp4.
        new_name="${arr[0]% *}.mp4"

        # And...
        printf '%s %s\n' "Use mp4box to combine the following files to a new file named" "$new_name"
        printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
    fi
done
```

Let's test it ( the name of the script is **sof** ):

```
$ ./sof
Use mp4box to combine the following files to a new file named ./001 aaaa.mp4
./001 aaaa part1.mp4
./001 aaaa part2.mp4
Use mp4box to combine the following files to a new file named ./003 cccc.mp4
./003 cccc part1.mp4
./003 cccc part2.mp4
Use mp4box to combine the following files to a new file named ./004 dddd.mp4
./004 dddd part1.mp4
./004 dddd part2.mp4
```

If that's indeed what you're trying to achieve, the proper arguments to `mp4box` can be created like this ( inside the `if (( ${#arr[@]} > 1 )); then` block, of course ):

```
# Create arguments to mp4box's -add option (i.e. file1 -cat file2 -cat file3 ...)
mp4args=("${arr[0]}"); for entry in "${arr[@]:1}"; do mp4args+=(-cat "$entry"); done
# Execute mp4box for current split files:
mp4box -add "${mp4args[@]}" "$new_name"
# Empty mp4args array here, or at the begining of the `for` loop.
mp4args=()
```

Let's put an `echo` before `mp4box` to be sure about what we're going to execute, and test it too:

```
$ ./sof
Use mp4box to combine the following files to a new file named ./001 aaaa.mp4
./001 aaaa part1.mp4
./001 aaaa part2.mp4
===
mp4box -add ./001 aaaa part1.mp4 -cat ./001 aaaa part2.mp4 ./001 aaaa.mp4
===

Use mp4box to combine the following files to a new file named ./003 cccc.mp4
./003 cccc part1.mp4
./003 cccc part2.mp4
===
mp4box -add ./003 cccc part1.mp4 -cat ./003 cccc part2.mp4 ./003 cccc.mp4
===

Use mp4box to combine the following files to a new file named ./004 dddd.mp4
./004 dddd part1.mp4
./004 dddd part2.mp4
===
mp4box -add ./004 dddd part1.mp4 -cat ./004 dddd part2.mp4 ./004 dddd.mp4
===
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming sane file names (no additional "." in the names, no weird other files in the current directory...):

```
for prefix in `ls | sed -e 's/ .*//' | uniq -d` ; do
  first=`ls $prefix* | head -1`
  name=`echo "$first" | sed -e 's/ part.+\\.//'
  cmd="mp4box -add '$first'"
  for rest in `ls $prefix* | tail +2` ; do
    cmd="$cmd -cat $rest"
  done
  $cmd $name
done
```

Untested. Test and tailor suitably.

EDIT: treat this as bash pseudo code, see comments for obvious problems with it.

Comment: You shouldn't [Parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and you shouldn't [read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Also, your method of building up the command as a string will fail for files with spaces in the name: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050